# Why does std::is_copy_constructible<T&&>::value return false?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

It seems that `is_copy_constructible<T&&>` is `false` even when `is_copy_constructible<T>` is `true` for identical types `T`. I've tested this with gcc and with clang and get the same results. Is this expected behaviour? Where does the standard define this? What is the reasoning for this behaviour?

Sample code which compiles with the error `"int&& doesn't work"`:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<int>::value, "int doesn't work");
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<int&>::value, "int& doesn't work");
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<int&&>::value, "int&& doesn't work");

    return 0;
}
```

I encountered this situation when I was trying to create a constraint on a template parameter to ensure that the template only works on copy constructible types. Will I need to create a special case for r-value reference types in order to get my template to work with r-value references to copy constructible types?

Comment: Forgetting the technical path: Think that you can copy an int or an int& but an int&& cannot be copied, only moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_copy_constructible<T>` is defined as `is_constructible<T, const T&>`. For `T = int &&`, the latter becomes `is_constructible<int&&, int&>`, which is clearly false:

```
int & f();
int && r(f());   // ill-formed
```

Comment: It's `int &&, int &`. The `const` is applying to the reference itself and so ignored.

Comment: So because of the way `is_copy_constructible<T>` is defined, it seems like what I actually want to do is strip away the references from the underlying type and test if the underlying type is copy-constructible. My templated function accepts its parameter as `const T&` and it just wants to know if the object referred to is copy-constructible.

Comment: @JordanMelo: That's what `remove_reference` is for!

Comment: Way ahead of you! Adding `remove_reference` gives me the behaviour I was looking for :)

Comment: @T.C. Good call. I recently changed my coding style such that I write `T const&` instead of putting it as `const T&` – I was confused about a point similar to that of the asker – and writing `T const&` reinforces this nuance.